# Clear thead of table element

Tags: jquery, html

I'm creating `thead` of table dynamically. Problem is, when I call my method for the first time it creates headers perfectly but when I call it again on the same table, it doesn't remove the previous headers. How can I clear previous `thead`?

**HTML**

```
 <table id="tblActivitySummary" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
     <span class="table-mainhead">Activity Summary</span>
</table>
```

**JQuery**

```
function CreateHTMLTable(tableId, displayColumnNames) {
    var columnNames = [];
    for (var k in displayColumnNames[0]) {
        columnNames.push(k);
    }
    var $toAttach = $("<thead><tr></tr></thead>");

    for (var i = 0; i < columnNames.length; i++) {
        var $thead = $("<th></th>");
        $thead.text(columnNames[i]);   //columnNames is array of string containing column names
        $toAttach.find("tr").append($thead);
    }
    $(tableId).append($toAttach);
}
```

I tried to empty like this before calling `CreateHTMLTable` but doesn't work:

```
$('#tblActivitySummary').empty();
CreateHTMLTable('#tblActivitySummary', displayColumnNames);
```

Comment: use **$('thead').empty()** instead to clear **THEAD**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is adding more `thead`s because you've used `.append`, which appends the contents in the specified container.

```
$(tableId).append($toAttach);
```

Instead of appending, you can directly use `.replaceWith()` to replace the tag with the new one.

```
$(tableId + " thead").replaceWith($toAttach);
```

**Edit**:

The following snippet adds the ability to add the `thead` first time when it doesn't exist:

```
$(tableId + " thead").length === 0 ? $(tableId).append($toAttach) : $(tableId + " thead").replaceWith($toAttach);
```

Comment: `$(tableId + " thead").length > 0` will return true if there is at least one `thead` present.

Comment: your code wont create `thead` for the first time if no thead exists. Right?